# How to direct an arrow from one node to the center of a diagonal arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows

I have a problem with positioning one arrow. The one from HA should be directed at the center of (JC-JS), but (JC-JS) doesn't work. I couldn't find a solution online. Can somebody help me out (see code and picture, I made a comment in the code where the mistake is). The best would be, if the height of HA is exactly between the one of JC and JS, how can I do that? Have a nice day!
Tobias

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\label{illustration}
\centering
\caption{bla}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=1cm and 4.4cm,
   ar/.style={->,>=latex},
   mynode/.style=
    {draw,
     text width=4.4cm,
     minimum height=1cm,
     align=center
    }
  ]
  \node[mynode] (JC) {JC};
  \node[mynode,right=of JC] (RA) {RA};
  \draw[ar] (JC) -> node[below] {bla} coordinate(JC-RA) (RA);
  \node[mynode, text width=2cm, above=of JC-RA] (HE) {HE};
  \node[mynode, text width=4cm, below=1.3 of JC-RA, dashed] (JS) {JS};
  \node[mynode, draw=none, text width=4cm, below=0 of JS] (H4) {bla};
  \node[mynode, text width=2cm, left=2 of JS] (HA) {HA};

 \draw[ar] (HE.south) ->  (JC-RA);
  \draw[ar] (HA.north east) ->  (JC-RA); %this arrow should be directed at the center of (JC-JS) just like the arrow before, but instead of JC-RA, it should be (JC-JS), but that doesn't work 
  \draw[ar] (JC.south) ->  (JS.west);
  \draw[ar] (JS.east) -> node[below=0.1cm, right] {bla}  (RA.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

SOLUTION, credits John Kormylo --->

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\label{illustration}
\centering
\caption{bla}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=1cm and 4.4cm,
   ar/.style={->,>=latex},
   mynode/.style=
    {draw,
     text width=4.4cm,
     minimum height=1cm,
     align=center
    }
  ]
  \node[mynode] (JC) {JC};
  \node[mynode,right=of JC] (RA) {RA};
  \draw[ar] (JC) -> node[below] {} coordinate(JC-RA) (RA);
  \node[mynode, text width=1.6cm, above=of JC-RA] (HE) {HE};
  \node[mynode, text width=4cm, below=1.3 of JC-RA, dashed] (JS) {JS};
  \node[mynode, text width=1.6cm, left=2.3 of JS] (HA) {HA};

 \draw[ar] (HE.south) ->  (JC-RA);
\draw[ar] (JC.south) -> node[above] {} (JS.west) coordinate[midway] (JCJS);
  \draw[ar] (HA.east) -> node[below] {}  (JCJS);
  \draw[ar] (JS.east) -> node[above] {}  (RA.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw[ar] (JC.south) ->  (JS.west) coordinate[midway] (JCJS);`   then draw the arrow from (HA.north east) to (JCJS).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Could you write an answer, please?

Comment: I added the solution in my post

Comment: Please ask @JohnKormylo to answer and remove the solution from your post or, if John is OK with it, move the solution to an answer. It gets confusing if answers are part of questions as people searching think there's no solution there and the question keeps showing up in the 'unanswered' list.

Answer (score 1):

I also cleaned up the code a little.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{bla}\label{illustration}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=1cm and 4.4cm,
   ar/.style={->,>=latex},
   mynode/.style=
    {draw,
     text width=4.4cm,
     minimum height=1cm,
     align=center
    }
  ]
  \node[mynode] (JC) {JC};
  \node[mynode,right=of JC] (RA) {RA};
  \draw[ar] (JC) -> (RA) coordinate[midway](JC-RA) ;
  \node[mynode, text width=1.6cm, above=of JC-RA] (HE) {HE};
  \node[mynode, text width=4cm, below=1.3 of JC-RA, dashed] (JS) {JS};
  \node[mynode, text width=1.6cm, left=2.3 of JS] (HA) {HA};

 \draw[ar] (HE.south) -> (JC-RA);
 \draw[ar] (JC.south) -> (JS.west) coordinate[midway] (JCJS);
 \draw[ar] (HA.east) -> (JCJS);
 \draw[ar] (JS.east) -> (RA.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

An alternative would be to use the calc tikzlibrary to define coordinate `($(JC.south)!.5!(JS.west)$)`, but the original solution is simpler.